# rvalue reference as an object field

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>  
struct Bar
{
    int nb_;
    Bar(int nb) :nb_(nb){}
    ~Bar()
    {
        std::cout << "~Bar" << "\n";
    }
}; 

struct Foo
{    
    template<class T>
    Foo(T&& param) :bar_(std::move(param))
    {
        std::cout << "Foo" << "\n";
    } 
    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "~Foo" << "\n";
    }

    Bar&& bar_;
};

int main()
{       
    { 
        Foo foo(Bar(1));
    }

    std::cin.ignore();
}

//Output:
Foo
~Bar 
~Foo
```

Is this program is legal C++? Does bar_ will become a dangling reference once the Foo constructor will be finished?

If this is not legal in term of C++ standard, when is it useful to have a rvalue reference as a field ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does `bar_` will become a dangling reference once the Foo constructor will be finished?

Not quite. It becomes a dangling reference at the point where the temporary created by `Bar(1)` is destroyed: at the end of the full-expression `Foo foo(Bar(1))`.

That also shows a usage example of rvalue reference members, for example `forward_as_tuple`:

```
struct woof
{
    using my_tuple = std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::string>;
    my_tuple m;

    woof(my_tuple x) : m(std::move(x)) {}
};

std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
woof w( forward_as_tuple(std::move(v), std::string{"hello world"}) );
```

`forward_as_tuple` can store rvalue references (here: in a `tuple<vector<int>&&, string&&>`), which still can be used by the ctor of `woof` to move `v` and the temporary created by `std::string{"hello world"}`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `bar_` will become a dangling reference after the constructor has finished.

It rarely makes sense to store a reference, but some cases exist. I don't think there is any difference between the different types of references. The stored reference references another object and you need to make sure that the object is still valid when the reference is used.

Note that if you write

```
Bar b( 1 );
Foo foo(std::move(b));
```

`foo` will not have moved `b`, it is just storing a reference to it. `b` is still valid and can be used. Only if you have a member of `Foo` which actually moves from the stored reference, `b` will be moved.

Comment: *"Yes, `bar_` will become a dangling reference after the constructor has finished."* I knew I had read this before in the Standard, now I think I've found the context: This statement applies to temporaries created in the ctor initializer (mem-initializer-list), but not to temporaries passed *to* a ctor as arguments, [class.temporary]/5.

Comment: @DyP Just to clarify: This statement refers to the specific example the OP gave where I assumed that by "after the constructor has finished" he meant to say "after the expression `Foo foo(Bar(1));`". You are of course correct to point out that this is not strictly the same and you got my +1 on your answer already :)

Comment: It just sounded so familiar I was confused for a moment of what it's referring to ;)